# Passing structure with list of structures to function

Tags: c

I have a function with prototype:

```
void procedureForEachWave(struct barge *Barge, struct settings *Settings, struct wave *Wave)
```

In another function I have a another structure called `threadData`, which I use to send information to functions that run on several threads, and one of the element of this structure is a list of `struct wave`, so the short vesion of this code goes:

```
struct threadData data;
data.waveList = (struct wave*) malloc(sizeof(struct wave)*nrOfWaves);
```

I use this in another function, where I basically first send a pointer to the structure data, and then inside this function the "procedureForEachWave" function is called in a loop like this:

```
procedureForEachWave(data->Barge, data->Settings, &data->waveList[i]);
```

This works fine. However, I also want to do an analysis where I only use one wave, meaning that the list only contains one element, and I therefore don't need to call the first function. I only want to do this:

```
procedureForEachWave(Barge, Settings, &data.waveList[0]);
```

but this does not work. Why? and how do I get it to work? To clarify, data is now declared as a variable, not a pointer, and Barge and Settings are pointers already. The waveList is declared like this:

```
data.waveList = (struct wave*) malloc(sizeof(struct wave));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work" ? Do you get a compilation error or run time error or is it giving you run time results which you are not expecting ? If compiler/linker is complianing, please post the exact error message.

Comment: I am not able to understand this even after multiple reads. Pls consider rephrasing your Qn in simple terms

Comment: Doesn't work - you mean doesn't compile or doesn't work as you excpect at runtime?

Comment: yes offcourse: the problem is that I get "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" message when I run the program (in XCode). It happens when a function tries to access an element in the wave structure, which should come from &data.waveList[0].

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing ANYTHING about what is going on inside of `procedureForEachWave`, it is difficult (if not impossible) to tell what the problem is.

However, it does look like `data` is being used differently between the call that works and the one that doesn't.  If they are using the same `data`, the call should be the same (substituting 0 for `i`).  If they are different, please provide a definition of this other `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the code fragment:

```
extern void wave_function(struct wave *);
struct wave value     =   { ... };
struct wave array[10] = { { ... } };

wave_function(&value);
wave_function(array);
wave_function(&array[5]);
```

The called function cannot tell from the pointer it was given whether it was passed a pointer to a single value or a pointer to an array of values.  The calling function and the called function must agree on how the pointer will be used, perhaps by including the number of elements in the array as a separate argument:

```
extern void alt_wave_function(struct wave *, size_t);

alt_wave_function(&value, 1);
alt_wave_function(array, 10);
alt_wave_function(&array[5], 3);
```

Note that if the size passed with the pointer `&value` was larger than 1, you'd be into undefined behaviour.  The other two calls are both wholly legitimate: the third one, though, effectively passes a three-row subset of the array to the function.

So, inside a function, any pointer argument can be treated as a pointer to a single value, or as the pointer to the first item in an array of values.  Both are correct.  Indeed, you can even write:

```
void wave_function(struct wave *ptr)
{
}

void wave_function(struct wave ptr[])
{
}
```

These are equivalent declarations (but only in the argument list).  You can even include a size in the array notation, though that conveys no information to the function, unless you dress it up in C99 syntax:

```
void wave_function(struct wave array[static 4])
{
}
```

This notation means that the caller must guarantee that there are at least 4 elements in the array passed to this version of `wave_function`.